# How to filter a post in the Tag Cloud widget, using tags of a media library image attached to the post?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags, attachments, media-library

I hope my question is rather common.

There are some posts. These posts have images as attachments. These images are stored in the Media Library and have tags based on custom taxonomy. Obviously, if these image tags are displayed in the Tag Cloud widget in the front-end, they are useless, as they do not search for the posts the images are atached to.

What are the optimal ways for making these image tags to search for corresponding Posts through the Tag Cloud?

Thanks.